# Multiple routes matched at the same time - Strange Express behavior

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am wondering if the following express behavior is valid :

In this example, making a GET request "GET /count" will trigger/execute both routes /count and /:mail.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/count', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!1')
})

app.get('/:mail', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!2')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

When the /:mail is triggered, the output will be : "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

My question is : Isn't it obvious for express to match only one single route at once ?